# Rspec + Capybara throws no match RoutingError on /auth/developer that works fine in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

The app is using a basic omniauth login strategy. My routes include:

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: 'pages#root'

get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
post '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create' # Needed for developer strategy
```

I've just begun implementing some feature tests (first one, no unit tests yet). It fails on the first `visit root_path` call.

Diagnosing this is difficult because the `localhost:3000/auth/developer` works fine in my development environment. Is there a reason my routes wouldn't be loading in test?

Here's the error:

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/auth/developer"
```

For good measure, I ran `$ RAILS_ENV=test rake routes` and got back:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
    root GET    /                                  pages#root
         GET    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format) sessions#create
         POST   /auth/:provider/callback(.:format) sessions#create
```

EDIT: Since reading the [Omniauth Gem Docs](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing), I've implemented the following config:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:developer]
  end
  ...
end
```

That did nothing to help.

Here's the *only* spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'user joins first conversation' do
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:developer] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
      :provider => 'developer',
      :uid => 'justuseapen@gmail.com'
    })

    scenario 'they receive quick tutorial from Alan' do
    visit root_path
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'any@email.com'
    click_button 'Sign In'
    expect(page).to have_css '#messages', 'My foobar'
  end
end
```

Comment: Your root is not `/auth/developer` is it? Show us your spec code

Comment: Have you read this?: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Comment: The root is pages#root which is filtered by a :require_current_user. Thanks for the resource @zetetic. I'm trying to config my rails_helper to run omniauth in test mode.

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to get `/auth/developer` - none of the routes will match that as a URL. The root URL is `/` and will direct to the `root` action on the `PagesController`... the only other route you have defined is `/auth/:provider/callback` which also does not match `/auth/developer` it would have to be something like `/auth/developer/some_callback` to match